# Download Code - Linq C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code working, it uploads a PDF document to SQL Server express, and shows it to DataGridView.  How can I download or view (by default pdf reader) the uploaded file?

Most codes snippets I found were for ASP.NET; this is Winforms.  Thank you.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (docnoTextBox.Text == "" && docfromTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot save empty strings");            
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            iteisDataContext das_db = new iteisDataContext();
            Document newDoc = new Document();
            newDoc.docid = docnoTextBox.Text;
            newDoc.docdate = docdateDateTimePicker.Value;
            newDoc.postdate = DateTime.Now;
            newDoc.doctype = cboDocType.Text;
            newDoc.docfrom = docfromTextBox.Text;

            //Convert string to linq.binary
            Binary pdfFile = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(ofdMain.FileName);

            // And back to string - dae pa ini confirmado!
            //string fileUpload = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pdfFile.ToArray());

            newDoc.docupload = pdfFile;
            newDoc.docsubject = docsubjectTextBox.Text;
            newDoc.notes = notesTextBox.Text;

            // Update database
            das_db.Documents.InsertOnSubmit(newDoc);
            das_db.SubmitChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Document Saved.", "Success",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: What's LINQ got to do with this?

Answer (score 2):

In WinForms you could use the Acrobat reader ActiveX control (Add Reference -> COM Components -> `AcroPDF.PDF`) to display the PDF file directly inside your application. This requires Adobe Reader to be installed on the client computer:

```
var pdf = new AxAcroPDF();
pdf.LoadFile(@"c:\test.pdf");
```

Another possibility is to open the PDF with the default program on the client computer using the Process.Start method:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\test.pdf");
```

In both cases you need to store the PDF in a temporary file after reading it from your database.

Comment: Beat me by a sec. +1 from me.

Comment: Hello Darin, Please post an example how to use this line of code to view or download file from sql server. "string fileUpload = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pdfFile.ToArray());
" And this "Process p = new Process();". Thank you, I'm still learning